# How to correctly upload Amazon S3 Images in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-2.0

There are a few questions about this, but somehow none of them have fixed my issue. All I want to do is to display Amazon S3 images on my website.

Some info:

I'm hard-coding the direct link to the image source attribute (*for test purposes*), but the image never appears.

Whenever I access the direct link, i get a grey square tiny image (*not the same image i tried to upload*).

I have also made my bucket policy public and updated CORS. Here's their setup:

Bucket Policy

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

How I am uploading:

```
  var request = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "testbucket",
            Key = "test",
            InputStream = new MemoryStream(image.Content),
            ContentType = image.MimeType // "image/png"
        };

  var response = await Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
```

I believe the uploading is wrong, but i haven't found any **ASP.NET** Core tutorials on how to successfully upload a `byte[]` image file. What could possibly be wrong ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Whenever I access the direct link, i get a valid base64 image on html."*  I'm not quite sure what this means, but your image needs to be binary, not base64, in a file.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i was getting a raw base64 file whenever i tried to access the image. However, when i uploaded a file directly (not programatically) amazon s3 worked as expected (i could see the image on the website. I’ve updated my question because now I think it’s some issue with ASP.Net Core 2 and Amazon S3 compability.

Comment: I would suggest that `image.Content` contains a base64-representation of the uploaded image.  Neither your bucket nor your CORS policy should be relevant to uploads that appear to be working but result in unexpected payload.  Showing the code that clarifies what kind of object `image` and how you obtained it might be helpful.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i am kinda new to encoding and amazon s3. I have figured it out now. I’ll answer my own question thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand what was the issue. I was using Angular to send a base64 string to ASP.NET Core 2 and then was converting it to byte[] and sending to Amazon S3. For those who tried to upload a byte[] (from a base64) and got a small tiny squared image on amazon S3, maybe you’re using the wrong part of base64 string.

Basically, you shouldn’t use the first part of the string, the one with content similar to: image/png;base64. You should only convert to byte array the content after the “ , “. I did not know that.

There are several tutorials on converting from base64 to byte array.